# Custom role to read anything underneath an azure subsctiption for example under resource groups

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have some test code that is able to list resource groups under subscription and inside the subscription even list resources like virtual network, etc. I am experimenting with custom templates and there I tried creating a custom role to read the same stuff. My actions in the custom role might be incorrect because I am able to list the resource group but not the networks underneath it. Can someone tell me what is wrong. I tried first with asterisk, but then added one more line and that did not help either.

Here is the template. The role is fairly simple, but I am not clear why I cannot see the network inside the RG with below permissions

```
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "actions": {
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue": [
         "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/*/read",
         "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/read"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Array of actions for the roleDefinition"
      }
    },
    "notActions": {
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue": [ ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Array of notActions for the roleDefinition"
      }
    },
    "roleName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "allcustomreadscheck1234",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Role created via azure cli..."
      }
    },
    "roleDescription": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Subscription Level Deployment of a Role Definition",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Detailed description of the role definition"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables":{
    "roleDefName": "[guid(subscription().id, string(parameters('actions')), string(parameters('notActions')))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions",
      "apiVersion": "2018-07-01",
      "name": "[variables('roleDefName')]",
      "properties": {
        "roleName": "[parameters('roleName')]",
        "description": "[parameters('roleDescription')]",
        "type": "customRole",
        "isCustom": true,
        "permissions": [
          {
            "actions": "[parameters('actions')]",
            "notActions": "[parameters('notActions')]"
          }
        ],
        "assignableScopes": [
          "[subscription().id]"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What you are saying is that you want to create a custom role with reader permissions to everything? Why not just copy the Reader role?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason that you can't read the virtual networks is that `Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/read` is not allowed to this role.
You can see how the built-in roles are defined on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#reader.

You can see for example how the Reader role is defined:

```
{
  "assignableScopes": [
    "/"
  ],
  "description": "Lets you view everything, but not make any changes.",
  "id": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/acdd72a7-3385-48ef-bd42-f606fba81ae7",
  "name": "acdd72a7-3385-48ef-bd42-f606fba81ae7",
  "permissions": [
    {
      "actions": [
        "*/read"
      ],
      "notActions": [],
      "dataActions": [],
      "notDataActions": []
    }
  ],
  "roleName": "Reader",
  "roleType": "BuiltInRole",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions"
}
```

As you can see, it defines `*/read` as its actions, allowing it to do the action I mentioned in the beginning.
So you can use this to allow reading of anything, otherwise you might need to either explicitly define which resources they can read with `Microsoft.Network/*/read`/`Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/read` or you can exclude ones they cannot read through notActions.